# Exclude quantitizer from regular expression`

Tags: regex

I have a quantifier regular expression that matches a 5digit code `[0-9]{5}`.
How can I exclude any matched of the above quantifier?

I tried `[^([0-9]{5})]` but it seems it doesn't work.

Test data follows:

**including:**

```
12345678875645 (will be matched)
pppppaaaaa     (will be matched)
52p26          (will be matched)
123            (will be matched)
```

**excluding:**

```
12345          (won't be matched)
```

Comment: can you give an actual example and the expected result?

Comment: anything **digit** length except with **5** length?

Comment: This question needs more detail. Sample data, what language you're using, what expected output?

Comment: FYI boundaries were important, thanks for those who noticed it/ All your solutions were excellent, I will up everyone's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that you need a `regex` to match all things **except** **5 digits**  length

You simply need to use **negative lookahead assertion** for excluding 5 digits. that is it.

## [`\b(?!\d{5}).+|.{6,}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/KZNjyK/1)

It excludes **only 5 digits** not anything else

Comment: Actually the check is going to happen to a set of reward strings. The old ones were 5digit but the new ones could be anything alphanumeric in variable length up to X letters.

Comment: I think he wants to get anything except a 5-digit number

`pppppaaaaa (will be matched)`

Comment: @Panagiotis. take a look please

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
^(\d{1,4}|\d{6,})$
```

This won't match numbers with exactly 5 digits

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/sHvRMA/1

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative look ahead:

```
/(?!^[0-9]{5}$)^.+$/
```

```js
var rexp = /(?!^[0-9]{5}$)^.+$/;
var str = ['12345', '12345678875645', 'pppppaaaaa', '52p26', '123'];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  console.log(str[i] + ' - ' + (rexp.test(str[i]) ? 'matched' : 'did not match'));
}
```

Comment: **Cool and Nice**